# How to prove $ 1+1 + 2+ 2^2 +2^3 + \cdots + 2^{30}= 2^{31}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

This is true?  $ 1+1 + 2+ 2^2 +2^3 + \cdots + 2^{30}= 2^{31}$, How to prove?

Comment: Do you know anything about geometric series?

Comment: no i dont any thing

Comment: Well, then get a calculator....

Comment: $1+1=2, 1+1+2=4, 1+1+2+4=8, 1+1+2+4+8=16$. Starting to see a pattern?

Comment: ok, and then pattern

Comment: "Calculus" is clearly not the right tag here.  I didn't want to use the odious algebra-precalculus tag, especially since this is not really needed for calculus, so I created the elementary-algebra tag. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think an elementary-algebra tag is way too vague, especially since this question fits squarely in the scope of [tag:algebra-precalculus].

Comment: @T.Bongers : It doesn't fit within what could reasonably be called "algebra-precalculus", but rather within what _is_ called that.

Comment: @Soroush : I up-voted the question, and others have down-voted it and closed it.  Probably the reason why they have done that is it's phrased in language resembling that suitable for assigning homework.  That causes some people to suspect you may have copied a homework question without understanding it.  They ought to explain that here in comments but usually they neglect to do so.  In this instance I think someone may be following that rule in something of a knee-jerk fashion.

Comment: @MichaelHardy So in your opinion, the fight for changing what "algebra precalculus" means starts with polluting math.SE tags?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : So any proposed change that you disagree with is "pollution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} x^k = 1 + x\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k \\
\Rightarrow (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k = 1 - x^{n+1} \\
\Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k = \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1 - x}
$$

Now your sum is just

$$
1 + \sum_{k=0}^{30} 2^k = 1 + \frac{1 - 2^{31}}{1- 2}\\
= 1 + 2^{31} - 1 \\
= 2^{31}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. Try it for some small values to convince yourself. To prove it, note that the sum after the first term is a geometric series and sum it. For the specific case, you can just compute both sides. That is a fine proof.

Answer (score 1):

For computing the geometric sum $S=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n$ compare it to
$$
x\cdot S=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{n+1}
$$
to find that the difference is
$$
(x-1)\cdot S=x^{n+1}-1
$$
Now set $x=2$…

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know anything about geometric series, $2^n-1=1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1}$ can be easily proved by induction.

It's clearly true for $n=1$.  Suppose it's true for some $n=k$ and consider $n=k+1$.

$$1+2+\cdots+2^{k-1}+2^k=(2^k-1)+2^k=2\cdot 2^k-1=2^{k+1}-1.$$